# Sequelize appears to be updating every associated record on add?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

It appears that when I use the addSomething function to create an additional association, Sequelize updates every existing association marking the associated id field NULL, then REupdates every one of them again WITH the associated id. Why in the world would they do this and more importantly, how can I stop it?

```
number.addCall(call).success(function(call){
  console.log("addCall");
});
```

And console output:

```
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CAe843623d58ae3453910ce0a8e6ae065b',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='completed',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"='6',"id"=24,"createdAt"='2013-04-24 18:12:44.695000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.392000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=NULL WHERE "id"=24 RETURNING *
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CA8045f80aee98e334d57deb3a31140f7f',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='completed',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"='5',"id"=25,"createdAt"='2013-04-25 17:35:46.919000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.393000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=NULL WHERE "id"=25 RETURNING *
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CAd0c476c2f790944cd4962651a86ee299',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='completed',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"='6',"id"=26,"createdAt"='2013-04-30 18:42:01.838000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.393000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=NULL WHERE "id"=26 RETURNING *
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CAe843623d58ae3453910ce0a8e6ae065b',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='completed',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"='6',"id"=24,"createdAt"='2013-04-24 18:12:44.695000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.394000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=1 WHERE "id"=24 RETURNING *
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CA8045f80aee98e334d57deb3a31140f7f',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='completed',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"='5',"id"=25,"createdAt"='2013-04-25 17:35:46.919000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.395000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=1 WHERE "id"=25 RETURNING *
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CAd0c476c2f790944cd4962651a86ee299',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='completed',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"='6',"id"=26,"createdAt"='2013-04-30 18:42:01.838000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.395000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=1 WHERE "id"=26 RETURNING *
Executing: UPDATE "Calls" SET "from"='+16159572942',"to"='+16159002621',"callsid"='CAca700726a04726c976baeec0b3b11714',"direction"='inbound',"callstatus"='ringing',"fromcity"='NASHVILLE',"fromstate"='TN',"fromzip"='37115',"fromcountry"='US',"callduration"=NULL,"id"=27,"createdAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.328000',"updatedAt"='2013-04-30 19:19:38.396000',"deletedAt"=NULL,"PhonenumberId"=1 WHERE "id"=27 RETURNING *
addCall
```

All it needs to do is update ONE record, the one that the variable "call" represents. This will eventually crush the db once there are thousands or more calls associated with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue in pre 1.6.0 versions, including the betas. Updating to 1.6.0 made this behave as expected.